# Async callback and timeout not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jestjs, puppeteer

I am not sure why I get this error. I call the `done()` function and define `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`. Why is it throwing this error.

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

```
describe('Puppeteer', () => {
    let originalTimeout;

    beforeEach(function () {
        originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    });

  it('Logs in, redirects and does something', async (done) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: [
        '--incognito'
      ]
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('localhost:3000/login');
    ... // Login Credentials
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' }); // redirects
    ... // perform some action on website
    expect(a < b)
      .toEqual(true);
    browser.close();
    done();
  });

    afterEach(function () {
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });
});
```

That doesnt do anything neither

```
describe('...', () => {
  it('...', async (done) => {
    ....
  }, 10000);
});
```

Writing it this way works, but why?

```
describe('Puppeteer', () => {
  it('Logs in, redirects and does something', () => {
    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: [
          '--incognito'
        ]
      });
      ....
      expect(a < b)
        .toEqual(true);
      browser.close();
    })();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `done` is used for callback.
- `async` is used for promises.

Look how their example does not have two at same time.

[image]

`done` and `async` will not work at same time. Remove `done` if you are using `async`.